# Get column name, data type, size and comments of Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes, tablecolumn, database-metadata

How can I get column name, data type, size and comments of table?

I tried

```
SELECT all_tab.column_name, all_tab.data_type, all_tab.data_length, col_com.COMMENTS 
    FROM all_tab_columns all_tab
        JOIN user_col_comments col_com ON all_tab.TABLE_NAME = col_com.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE all_tab.TABLE_NAME='MY_TABLE'
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: your query works ok to me. check name of table and that you have permissions to the table

Comment: What does 'didn't work' mean ? Wrong results ? Error ? You are also joining ALL_ and USER_  views so only tables that are actually owned by the schema you are running from will be shown.

Comment: @BriteSponge, wrong results.

Comment: did you check owner of the table? is it correct one? bcz you are using `all_` views and this can be table from different schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add column name connection:

```
SELECT all_tab.column_name,
       all_tab.data_type,
       all_tab.data_length,
       (SELECT COMMENTS
          FROM user_col_comments t
         where t.TABLE_NAME = all_tab.TABLE_NAME
           and t.COLUMN_NAME = all_tab.column_name)
  FROM all_tab_columns all_tab
 WHERE all_tab.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
```

Answer (score 1):

The USER_ views show information about objects, tables in this case, that are owned by the schema user you are connecting as. The ALL_ views show information abut objects that the connected schema user has permissions to see.

If you are only interested in objects that are created by the schema owner then by all means use the USER_ views.

However, you probably want;

```
SELECT all_tab.owner,
       all_tab.table_name,
       all_tab.column_name,
       all_tab.data_type,
       all_tab.data_length,
       col_com.comments
FROM   all_tab_columns all_tab
       JOIN all_col_comments col_com
          ON  all_tab.table_name = col_com.table_name
          AND all_tab.owner = col_com.owner
WHERE  all_tab.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

This certainly works for me but you might want to consider also retrieving the DATA_PRECISION and DATA_SCALE

Comment: @AlexanderYau - Given that this works for me do you think that simply repeating that it shows the wrong results gives ANY information about what the issue may be. How about who you are logged in as, who owns the table you are interested in, what is wrong with the results, wrong columns, wrong table. How about what you actually expect to see.  Try to imagine walking up to a busy colleague, showing them the query and saying 'Wrong results'. What would your colleague say ?

Comment: Your scripts is good, but it just repeats the result and it is very annoying when the length of column is very large and I have to spend some time to precess these repeated results. Sorry, I have no colleagues and I'm a newbie in Oracle.